# Robotframework Issue - Cannot run ride.py (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework, rpa, robotframework-ide

I have installed the following programs in order to run robotframework on Pyhton 3.7

wxPython: `pip install -U wxPython`

Robotframework-ride: `pip install robotframework-ride`

When I run the command on cmd `ride.py` a mensage shows thay `there is no linked app to execute the action. I should install the app or create an association on Standard App Setup`

Anyone can help me with it?
Thanks in dvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention, but I assume your operating system is Windows, because it does not have an associated program to run python programs. If that is the case, on Windows you can start from command window with `ride`.

On any system, you can start RIDE with `python -m robotide.__init__`.

Also be careful with the wxPython version you install, because only 4.0.7.post2 is the recommended.

We have this mentioned on our RIDE's project page, [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/), look for README, FAQ, and Releases.